# How to override delegated attribute in factory_girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, factory-bot

I have an attribute delegated to an associated object (AR/Postgres) and am attempting to override it when calling the factory.

```
class Patient
    delegate :email, to: :credential
    has_one :credential, as: :owner,  dependent: :destroy
end

class Credential
    belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :patient do
    first_name 'Jane'
    last_name 'Patient'
    dob Date.parse('2005-01-11')
    gender 'Female'
    zipcode '80202'

    after(:build) do |user|
      create(:credential, owner: user)
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :credential do
    password '!Secret15'
    password_confirmation { password }
    agree_to_terms true

    sequence :email do |n|
     "user#{n}@bar.com"
    end
  end
end
```

And the call:

```
create(:patient, email: 'new@email.com')
```

It is simply not working, and the attribute is getting set by the default sequence.

Scoured their docs and Google and couldn't find an answer. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

factory_girl doesn't do anything with `delegate`. You need to pass `email` to the `:credential` factory yourself. Attributes aren't available in callbacks, so get `email` from the evaluator which is the second argument to the callback block:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :patient do
    # other attributes

    after(:build) do |user, evaluator|
      create(:credential, owner: user, email: evaluator.email)
    end
  end
end
```

Documented here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes